# Laravel Task: How can I pass params to use in method?

Tags: php, laravel, console, scheduled-tasks

I'm setting up a new Task with Laravel and this task calls to a method from other class, this method needs a parameter.

I have been reading doc from [Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/artisan#arguments) this says I have to include the param in $signature among `{}` And I did it.

```
protected $signature = 'cmd:taskTest {id}';
```

In my handle function (in command class)

```
    public function handle()
    {
        WebController::downloadFile(); // downloadFile needs param
    }
```

And my method, which is called by handle.

```
public static function downloadFile($warehouseId){
//do something
}
```

I have tried writing this in prompt:

```
php artisan cmd:taskTest 1
```

It returned an error because it needs the id to find all information in database about this id.

To create the command I ran this:

```
php artisan make:command
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can retrieve it with the `argument` method.

```
WebController::downloadFile($this->argument('id'));
```

For more information: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/artisan#command-io

Comment: Thanks you! 
And in $signature have to add {'id'}

protected $signature = 'cmd:taskTest {id}';

Comment: @S.Wasta What do you mean? Didn't you already have the `id` in the signature?

Comment: Yes, I did. It's plus information in case I read this in a future or if anyone else read it. Thanks again!

Comment: @S.Wasta Np. Please mark my answer as correct when you have a minute. :)